# Grails "checked" exception

Tags: exception, grails, grails-orm

I need to throw exception from Grails service. But :

1. The exception has to be "checked" so that Hibernate would not rollback upon throwing that exception. But looks like the base exception class in Grails ( "GrailsException" ) is unchecked (extented from RuntimeException). Is there any checked exception exists in Grails that I can extend for my purpose? If not how can I create a checked exception class in Grails?
2. I am not very clear about when an exception can be called "checked" or "unchecked"? May be, more specifically, my question is what is a checked exception and what are the characteristics of it?

I can provide code example if more clarification on my question is required. I tried:

```
class MyException extends GrailsException { 
}
```

and it's rolling back the transaction on this exception

Thanks in advance

Comment: How/where do you 'catch' this exceptions after throwing?

Comment: For Q.2 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explaination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no requirement that you subclass any Grails exception - extend `java.lang.Exception` or any other checked exception as your base class.